# Writing in two sessions from the same file (PHP)

Tags: php, session

I want to make it possible for the administrator to log in as a fontend user from the backend. Right now I'm using two sessions (sessions with different names), one for the admin and one for the frontend.

Is it possible to write in the first session, close it and then open a new session?

This is a simplified version of what I attempted but failed:

```
session_name('admin_session');
session_start();
// use first session without generatring any output
session_close();

session_name('frontend_session');
session_start();
// use the second session
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a session is actually for. A session uniquely identifies the browser opening your site. I don't see why you'd need to double confirm this. You should put your admin privileges in another place.

Comment: This is how the site was programmed, I cannot do anything about it.

The fontend checks for privileges in one session (identified by it's name) and the backend checks for privileges in a different session. For this I need access to both sessions.

Comment: So are you using `session_destroy()` or `session_write_close()`? Because `session_close()` doesn't exist. I'm also confused about how it can check for two 'different' sessions, I was under the impression that PHP could only store one cookie called PHPSESSID in the browser per domain.

Comment: @Byron. There was already written code I tried to understand.
So before sesstion_start(); the functions session_name(".."); session_save_path(SESSION_WRItE_DIR) and session_set_cookie_params(0, ADMIN_DIR) are called.

As for your first question, I'm using session_write_close().

Comment: @Byron: The session name is the name of the cookie as well, so you can have any number of sessions if for some reason you want that.  I'm not sure i see a use for it, though.

Answer (score 2):

I have provided the facility for an administrator to switch to a "user" in the past.

I did this by serializing the admin user's $_SESSION and then storing that string as $_SESSION['adminData'] before overwriting all the other session vars with those of the user he was logging in as, and redirecting to the main page. The only different feature on the main page was an if test against $_SESSION['adminData'] that provided a "revert to admin" link... but to all intents and purposes, the administrator was now logged in as that user.
On clicking the "revert to admin" link, the code logic simply unserialized $_SESSION['adminData'].