# Fetching value stored in session on previous page with another session name using php

Tags: php, session

Here is my scenario.
I have 2 different pages with php

1). index.php page have session name declared as "session_one"

```
 $some_session = session_name("session_one");
 session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.net');
 session_start();
```

2). order.php page have session name declared as "sesson_random" (this is required to have another session name due to nature of implementation

```
 $some_session = session_name("sesson_random");
 session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.net');
 session_start();
```

now the issue that I am facing is that I have stored some values on index.php in session which I want to retrieve on order.php. I have tried many ways but unable to pass it.

Please note that I can not pass those values in query string of url.

Please help

Comment: you want to have seperate sessions but also to have them interact??

Comment: @Alex unfortunately no due to some reasons on the order page, I have some api which requires individual session otherwise this issue will not appear :(

Comment: if your sessions cannot interact you need another method of sharing data.  can you have a page that access both and transfers data? ( silly but a solution.. )

Comment: @Dave so how can we get the session values if we put one another page in between? Don't you think that the situation will be same when it reaches the order page?

Comment: i have no idea.. i don't understand the problem really and i'm not sure why you would want to restrict the session between two pages in the same app... shooting from the hip i guess... sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61381/discussion-between-user3550203-and-dave).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the data from the other session, by restoring it before you open the new one. All you have to do is use the `session_id` function. I tested it with this code right here: (index.php)

```
<?php

  session_name("session_one");
  session_start();

  $_SESSION["test"] = array("this is just a test");
  print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

Now, all you have to do is load the other session first and save the values into an array: (order.php)

```
<?php

  if(isset($_COOKIE["session_one"])){
    session_id($_COOKIE["session_one"]);
    session_name("session_one");
  }else{
    session_name("session_one");
  }
  session_start();
  $session = $_SESSION;
  session_write_close();

  print_r($session);

  if(isset($_COOKIE["session_random"])){
    session_id($_COOKIE["session_random"]);
    session_name("session_random");
  }else{
    session_name("session_random");
  }
  session_start();

  $_SESSION["other"] = array("this is another test");
  print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

The two sessions get combined. If you are not bothered by that, you should be good to go. Got some inspiration from here:
[Can multiple independent $_SESSIONs be used in a single PHP script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150355/can-multiple-independent-sessions-be-used-in-a-single-php-script)