# PHP Looking at different $_SESSION from same user

Tags: php, session-variables

I have a page that hosts one or more iframes, all from same domain.

for the main page and for each iframe I have a different session name (session_name()) so I can keep track of them. I know the name of each session.

If I am in one session - how can I modify one of the other sessions?

I tried (the overkill) this:

```
$session = session_name();
session_write_close();
unset($_SESSION);
session_name("othersession");  //a session that was initialized via the iframe
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "hello from other session";
session_write_close();
unset($_SESSION);
session_name($session);
session_start();
```

yet, when I look at the original session - the "hello.." message is there as well. Infact, its ONLY there and not in the othersession session..

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: `unset($_SESSION);` - don’t do that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php: _“Caution: Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.”_

Comment: Thanks, noted and fixed. But it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Fiddling with multiple sessions at the same time is always tricky, and error-prone. Can you first of all explain the purpose of this in a bit more detail? What exactly does _“so I can keep track of them”_ mean, what exactly do you need to do?

Comment: Hi CBroe - each iframe serves as a kinda of a component, keeping its own information as the JS calles for the backend script. They may use the same variable names but they will be kept at different sessions.

Comment: And what part of this needs access “across” different sessions? You call it the iframes’ “own information”, and yet there is a need to access it from somewhere else …?

Comment: The iframes are created dynamically by the main page. And at that time I want to put some information in their session. 
There may be more than one iframe with the same php file in it, but they differ in their data, which is in the session. Some generated locally, some passed by the main page.

Comment: Could you not handle that in one session though? Have a unique identifier for each iframe, and then store its data under `$_SESSION['unique_id']`. If you are only making JS requests that need to interact with the session, you can pass that unique ID as an additional parameter; if you need it for all kinds of request caused by/inside the iframe, then maybe an additional cookie, limited in scope to the iframe URL or (pseudo) “directory”, could pass on that id.

Comment: You are correct, this is how I started. But each session contains a fair amount of data. Not too much to be called a session but not something I want to accumulate.

Comment: Don’t see why the amount of data stored in a session should constitute a problem per se. But if you want to keep following the approach with individual sessions, check if https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150579/1427878 helps.